# When only equals is override, why list finds item as true?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, equals, hashcode

I know that both hashcode and equals need to be overriden. I tried below program and was wondering why list is able to search student when set couldn't search student when only equals is overridden:

```
import java.util.*;

class Student {
private int id;
private String name;

public Student(int id, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;

    if (!(obj instanceof Student))
        return false;

    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    return this.getId() == ((Student) obj).getId();
}
}

public class StudentHashcodeEquals {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student alex1 = new Student(1, "Alex");
    Student alex2 = new Student(1, "Alex");

    System.out.println("alex1 hashcode = " + alex1.hashCode());
    System.out.println("alex2 hashcode = " + alex2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Checking equality between alex1 and alex2 = " + alex1.equals(alex2));

    List<Student> studentsLst = new ArrayList <Student>();
    studentsLst.add(alex1);
    studentsLst.add(alex2);

    System.out.println("Arraylist size = " + studentsLst.size());
    System.out.println("Arraylist contains Alex = " + studentsLst.contains(new Student(1, "Alex")));

    HashSet <Student> students = new HashSet <Student>();
    students.add(alex1);
    students.add(alex2);

    System.out.println("HashSet size = " + students.size());
    System.out.println("HashSet contains Alex = " + students.contains(new Student(1, "Alex")));
}
}

/*
alex1 hashcode = 366712642
alex2 hashcode = 1829164700
Checking equality between alex1 and alex2 = true
Arraylist size = 2
Arraylist contains Alex = true
HashSet size = 2
HashSet contains Alex = false
*/
```

When student was inserted into list, I'm assuming that it would insert it into 2 different buckets as the hashcode implementation is not prsent and default object hashcode would get kicked in and it'll store them into 2 different hash codes and when searching for another object, it has to first locate the bucket via hash code but hash code implementation is not there, then how list is able to still identify it whereas set does not??

Thanks!

Comment: A `List` allows duplicates. Why should it check the hashcode?

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't use the hashCode. Typically only collections with "Hash" in the name such as `HashMap` and `HashSet` do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists do not use the hashcode of an object. Depending on their type, they store an array of references to the objects.

If you call `contains` on a list, it will iterate through the list using `.equals()` to check if the object is in the list.